# How can I add gridlines to a SharePoint modern list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, table

Since modern SP doesn't really have an easy way to create a table with images, I've created a list with a few columns (including one for images).  Is there a way to add gridlines to a modern list, either an OOTB option, or JSON?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Acording to my research, there is no OOTB way to add gridlines to modern list. However, you can add gridlines to classic list.

**You can try to the following workaround:**

**A:**

a1.Go to the list and switch to **classic mode**

a2.Add a **Hyperlink or Picture** column

[image]

a3.Go to **Settings** (Upper right corner) >> **Edit Page** >> Select **Add a Web Part** >> **Media and Content** >> Select **Content Editor** >> Click OK.

[image]

a4.On the Content Editor web part, click "**Click here to add new content**" >> **Edit Source**

[image]

a5.Add below CSS in Web Part's "Edit Source":

```
<style>
    /* ---------- Table Rows ----------*/
    /* Set background for every row */
    .ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr {
        background: white;
    }

    /* Set border for every row */
    .ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr td{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #AFAFAF !important; /* !important needed over override SharePoint inline style */
        border-left: 1px solid #AFAFAF !important;
        border-right: 1px solid #AFAFAF !important;
    }

    /* Set background for every alternating row */
    .ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr.ms-alternating {
        background: #E2E3E5;
    }

    /* ---------- Table Header Row ----------*/
    /* Remove background set in SharePoint's general data table style */
    .ms-listviewtable tr.ms-viewheadertr {
        background: transparent;
    }

    /* Modify background color */
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh-icon, /* Input box and attachment icon */
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh, /* Text */
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th /* Text */ {
        background: #2E4C70;
    }

    /* Modify background color on hover */
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh:hover,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2:hover,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th  {
        background-color: #273C51;
        border-color: #273C51;
    }

    /* Modify font color */
    .ms-viewheadertr a,
    .ms-viewheadertr div {
        color: white;
    }

    /* Modify font color on hover */
    .ms-viewheadertr a:hover,
    .ms-viewheadertr div:hover {
        color: white;
    }
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh-icon:last-child {
        display:none;
    } 
</style>​​<br/>
```

[image]

[image]

**B:**

Create a **SPFx webpart** to display list items in a table. You can refer to **[this article](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/display-sharepoint-list-items-in-a-table-using-spfx/)** to create SPFx.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  The table unfortunately needs to be in Modern format.  I also don't have elevated permissions to add SPFx.  I'm suggesting to the client that I display the images and columns in Gallery view...make the images clickable.  Hopefully she goes for it.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for you reply. If there is any solution in the future, I will share with you as soon as possible. Have a nice day!